# Mutexes in linux for processes

Tags: c, linux, mutex

How can I create a mutex in linux that will work with different processes and will have string name?

I want something similar to `CreateMutex` in Windows OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a semaphore - see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html.

This will give you the same as a mutex and you can name them

Answer (score 3):

There's a really nice freeware book [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/) with chapter on Interprocess communication especially *5.2 Processes Semaphores*:

> Linux provides a distinct alternate implementation of semaphores that
>   can be used for synchronizing processes (called process semaphores or
>   sometimes System V semaphores). Process sem- aphores are allocated,
>   used, and deallocated like shared memory segments.

There's really thorough explanation and many examples so I recommend taking a look.

Comment: "Advanced Linux Programming" link dead.